# React Modal Window issue - getting closed with Redux Call, whereas it works with Axios Call

Tags: reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

Opening a Modal Window, multiple times from same component with some different props.
Modal Window opens, then from a Select - onChange event, making a redux call using
**dispatch(fetchPreferredEmployee(empobj));**
automatically close the modal window.

I tried so many different codes.
Same call i made using AXIOS
**callFetchPreferredEmployee(empobj);**
within the modal window code, it works fine.

I am unable to resolve the issue, Pl. assist

Code is given below

**Modal Window**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Form, Select, Row, Col, Space } from 'antd';
import { AddForm } from '../../style/Style';
import { BasicFormWrapper } from '../../styled';

import { Modal } from '../../../components/modals/antd-modals';
// import { fetchPreferredEmployee } from '../../../redux/employee/actionCreator';
import moment from 'moment';

import axios from 'axios';
import config from '../../../config/api';

const { Option } = Select;

const TestModal1 = ({ visible, onCancel }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const sites = useSelector(state => state.sites.data);
  // const employees = useSelector(state => state.employees.data);
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(employees);
  }, [employees]);

  const changeSelect = siteid => {
    const todate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const fromdate = moment(todate)
      .add(-3, 'M')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let empobj = { fromdate: fromdate, todate: todate, siteid: siteid };
    // dispatch(fetchPreferredEmployee(empobj));
    callFetchPreferredEmployee(empobj);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    console.log('Submitted');
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    onCancel();
  };

  const callFetchPreferredEmployee = empobj => {
    axios
      .post(config.APIURL.employee.displayemppref, empobj)
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        setEmployees(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal width={1000} type="primary" title="Test" visible={visible} footer={null} onCancel={handleCancel}>
        <div className="project-modal">
          {visible ? 'visible' : 'none'}
          <br />
          <AddForm>
            <BasicFormWrapper>
              <Form form={form} name="contact" onFinish={handleOk}>
                <Row gutter={(0, 0)}>
                  <Col span={24}>
                    <div className="add-product-content">
                      <Space style={{ width: '100%' }} direction={'vertical'} size="middle">
                        <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
                          <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
                            <Form.Item
                              name="siteid"
                              initialValue=""
                              label="Select Site"
                              rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select Site!' }]}
                            >
                              <Select
                                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                showSearch
                                optionFilterProp="children"
                                filterOption={(input, option) =>
                                  option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                }
                                onChange={changeSelect}
                              >
                                <Option key={-2} value="" disabled>
                                  --- Select Site ---
                                </Option>
                                {sites &&
                                  sites.map((data, index) => (
                                    <Option key={index} value={data.id}>
                                      {data.sitename + ' (' + data.corporationno + ')'}
                                    </Option>
                                  ))}
                              </Select>
                            </Form.Item>
                          </Col>
                        </Row>

                        <Row gutter={[16, 16]} className="justify-content-center">
                          <Col xs={24} xl={24}>
                            <Button htmlType="submit" size="default" type="primary" key="submit">
                              Save Record
                            </Button>
                          </Col>
                        </Row>
                      </Space>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form>
            </BasicFormWrapper>
          </AddForm>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
export default TestModal1;
```

**Call to Modal Window**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import FeatherIcon from 'feather-icons-react';
import TestModal1 from './overview/TestModal1';

const SiteDayShiftAdd = ({ site, schdate }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const showAddForm = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const onCancel = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button size="small" key="btn5" type="light" onClick={() => showAddForm()}>
        <FeatherIcon icon="plus-square" size={14} /> 
      </Button>
      {visible?"visible":"none"}<br/>
      {visible && <TestModal1 visible={visible} site={site} schdate={schdate} onCancel={onCancel} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SiteDayShiftAdd;
```

**Showing Button Multiple times to open Modal Window**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import SiteDayShift from './SiteDayShift';
import SiteDayShiftAdd from './SiteDayShiftAdd';

const SiteWeekShift = ({ site, weekdays, weekshiftdata }) => {
  
  const DailyData = () => {
    return weekdays.map((week, index) => {
      const day1 = weekshiftdata.filter(item => item.schdate === week.wdate);
      if (day1.length === 0) {
        return (
          <Col span={3} key={index} className="dayshift">
            <SiteDayShiftAdd site={site} schdate={week.wdate}/>
          </Col>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Col span={3} key={index} className="dayshift">
            {day1.map((value, key) => (
              <SiteDayShift dayshiftdata={value} key={key} />
            ))}
          </Col>
        );
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Row gutter={[8, 8]} className="rowweekshift">
      <Col span={3} className="weekshift">
        {site.sitename}
        <br />
        {site.corporationno}
        <br />
        {site.siteid}
      </Col>
      <DailyData />
    </Row>
  );
};

export default SiteWeekShift;
```

Comment: you should check and debug your state in each level can you tell me what you see in console if you add this logs in each component: in TestModal1 before return ```console.log('----------------TestModal1', day1.length);```, in SiteWeekShift before ```if (day1.length === 0) {``` add ```console.log('----------------SiteWeekShift', day1.length);```  and in SiteDayShiftAdd before ```return``` add ```console.log('----------------SiteDayShiftAdd', visible);``` or you can create a repository in https://codesandbox.io/ and other developers can  test it better

Comment: Modal window is opening. 'visible' value is 'true'.
Modal closed when I call 'dispatch(fetchPreferredEmployee(empobj))'  or any other dispatch call

Comment: Issue Resolved. 
Solution: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523